# Hide Android Navigator shows a border

Tags: android, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

Im using react native navigation V1 and i set my nav bar transparent to true, in my IOS emulator looks good but in Android emulator show me something like a border, and i don't know how hide or remove this section.

//add this to change top bar navigator.
navigatorStyle: {
drawUnderNavBar: true,
navBarTranslucent: true,
navBarTransparent: true,
navBarBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
},

[Example how looks in Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8AVI.png)

Comment: That's not a border, its an elevation.  ANd you see it on top because you aren't displaying it at the top of the screen, you have a margin of some sort.

Comment: Also, in an android app the hamburger menu is usually on the left.  I don't know if you're bringing this in from some RN component, but it screams "I didn't care enough about your platform to actually make it look like an Android app".  Unless you're in an RTL language

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the solution thanks to you indicate that it is an elevation, and for the design ... well I think the same but the designer said in that place should go ...and the boss to.

Comment: i use topBarElevationShadowEnabled to solve this problem.